# strange characters in emacs shell buffer

Tags: emacs

My emacs lists strange escape characters in shell buffers:

```
me@ubuntu:~//configuration.template/hooks$ 
me@ubuntu:~//configuration.template/hooks$ ls
[0m[01;32mpost-commit[0m  [01;32mpost-commit~[0m  [01;32mpost-update[0m  
[01;32mpost-update~[0m  [01;32mpre-commit[0m  [01;32mpre-commit~[0m  [01;32mupdate[0m      update~
```

Anyone knows how I can fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These characters are color-changing control sequences. These sequences don't work in emacs `*shell*` buffers: instead they are displayed almost directly.

You should change your shell startup file (probably `~/.bashrc`) so that `ls` uses colors only in terminals that support them. In practice, this is likely to mean on every terminal type other than `dumb` (which is the terminal type provided in `*shell*` buffers). The terminal type is indicated in the `TERM` environment variable, so you can do something like this:

```
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ]; then
  alias ls='ls --color=auto'
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

"ansi-color-for-comint-mode" handles some color in shells.  It is not perfect, but it helps.  To turn it on, go to your shell and do `[M-x]ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on[RET]`.

-John

Comment: cool, this helps

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, if you are seeing this problem with the emacs grep command enter this at the command's prompt:

```
grep --color=NEVER -nH -e "searchstring" *
```